# How can I compute a sorted list of preferred terminal types?

Tags: console, terminal

In order to know what terminal to configure by default, I am looking to build a sorted list of preferred terminals.

Is there a comparison, preferably as a table of different terminal types including: `xterm` `xterm-new` `xterm-256color` `ansi` `vt100` `rxvt` `linux`.

Comment: Is there any chance you can phrase this in the form of a programming question?

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks, original one was asking for being close. I hope this is better.

Comment: The examples you gave are actually the most common that I've seen.  You should only set a type that your local terminal program can directly handle (otherwise applications may send back codes that screw up the display).  A `linux` terminal is a superset of `xterm`, `rxvt` is a little less capable, and `ansi` is sort of an extended `vt100`.  Most terminals can actually handle at least `vt102` so that is probably a good option before `vt100` as a last resort.  If you really want to see all possible names, run `toe`; also see `man 7 term` for details on naming.

Answer (score 0):

Based on current feedback, this is the **recommended sorted list**:

```
linux
xterm-256color
xterm-16color
xterm
ansi
vt100
rxvt
```

Just to be sure that we are sorting it properly, here are the rules:

```
linux > xterm
xterm > rxvt
xterm-256colors > xterm-16colors > xterm
ansi > vt100
vt102 > vt100
```

That's a community-wiki answer and **you are welcome to patch it**!

Comment: I would expect xterm-256color > xterm. And I wouldn’t include xterm-new, because that should be identical to xterm. Since xterm256-color is famously not installed in some popular distros, but you probably want more than eight colors, I use xterm-256color > xterm-16color > xterm when I’m trying to fallback.